# Passing the current File Path through to Powershell "SendTo" Script

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I'm trying to create a script that will let me copy an item from one location to a specified location in a PowerShell script. *Before it's mentioned, I know that I can put a shortcut in the Send To directory to perform this action, but I would like to add additional features (that's for a different time)*. I do apologize if there is another post relating to this, I've been looking for a day and a half to find one.

What I would like to know is if there is a way I can pass the current-item-that-I-am-right-clicking's file path to PowerShell to be used with the `Copy-Item` function. So if there is an item on the desktop, I can use this PowerShell script to `Copy-Item C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\File.ext` using the path as a variable (I believe that would be the appropriate term) from the "Send To" Selection in the context menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special to get the `Send To` context menu to send the file path to the target - it happens automatically.

Try the following:

Create a new script, let's call it `C:\Copy-SendTo.ps1`

```
param($SourceFile)

Copy-Item $SourceFile -Destination C:\your\specific\location\
```

Now, create a shortcut in `$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` with the name "CopyTo" and the following target:

```
%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\Copy-SendTo.ps1 -SourceFile
```

Now right-click a file on your desktop, select Send To > CopyTo.

Voila, your file has been copied

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen: Could you please provide an example with spaces in the different path names? Where do we have to set the quotes/double quotes?